# Rolling groups of kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a use case where I need to group user heart rate data every 30 min that is rolling every minute by user id.  Here is some sample incoming message

```
"user_id:1,hr="x",timestamp="12345789"
```

I am planning to create a Queue data structure, add 30 minutes of user data, call a ML api with that data as payload.  In the next minute, I need to remove the earliest data from the queue and add the latest data to the bottom of the queue and call the ML api again.

Is there an easier mechanism to do this in Kafka without maintaining my own queue data structure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty good use-case for Kafka Streams (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) (or maybe even for ksqlDB: https://ksqldb.io/).

You would do a windowed-aggregation using a hopping time window. Basically:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.stream("topic")
  .selectKey(...) // set "user_id" as key
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindow.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                        .advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
  .aggregate(...)
  .toStream()
  .to("outputTopic");
```